# Wood floor Transition Strip

Tags: flooring, hardwood

I’m working room-by-room in my house removing old wood flooring and installing new Cali Bamboo flooring.  Because Bamboo expands and contracts so much, the manufacturer suggests using transition strips every certain number of feet.  In my house, that means in between almost every room.

I tested to floor to be sure they were level and did all of the other pre-work suggested.  The floors went in beautifully and expanded and contracted like they were supposed to the first year.

There is just one thing that is driving me crazy.  The transition strip between the morning room and the living room won’t lay flat.  On the right side, it looks like the floor dips slightly under the frame of the door. Because of that, the transition strip doesn’t meet the floor.

I’ve researched and know I don’t want to glue or nail the transition strip to the floor or it won’t float.  The gap is killing me though.  Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get a longer strip and install it so it's tucked under the  door stop molding (I think it's door stop)?

Comment: Is that a 'T' moulding?  Maybe you can tack down the center of it with some construction adhesive (making sure you don't get it on the flooring.)